# JQuery custom confirm box callback error

Tags: jquery, caching, callback, confirm

In my project I am using a custom `Confirmation dialogue`, which uses the `callback` method of `JQuery`.

**Custom Function is**

```
function conf_close() {
$('.conf-cont-main').remove();
}
function confirmMsg(message, callback)
{
    $('.conf-main').remove();
    var cont = '<div class="conf-cont-main"><div class="conf-main">\n\
    <span class="conf-close" onclick="conf_close()">X</span>\n\
    <div class="conf-head">\n\
    Confirm Action\n\
    </div>\n\
    <div class="conf-body">\n\
    ' + message + '\n\
    </div>\n\
    <div class="conf-button">\n\
    <button class="btn btn-blue-3 btn-sm btn-flat" id="conf-yes">Yes</button>\n\
    <button class="btn btn-blue-3 btn-sm btn-flat" id="conf-no">No</button>\n\
    </div>\n\
    </div></div>';
    $('body').prepend(cont);
    $(document).on('click', '#conf-yes', function()
    {
        callback(true);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#conf-no', function()
    {
        callback(false);
    });
}
```

**I am calling this function as**

```
var c = confirmMsg('Are You Sure to Delete?', function(c) {
    if (c == true) {
        alert('true');
        conf_close();
        //ajax call
    }
    else{
        alert('false');
        conf_close();
    }
});
```

**The issue is, when i call `confirmMsg()` for the first time, it works as expected and alrt() will show once. When I call `confirmMsg()` for secondtime. it show alert 2 times and so on.**

How can I resolve this issue? 
Any help could be appreciated.
The example fiddle link is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8awjh9qm/)

Comment: may be problem with `ajax` call. can you write your ajax call here?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi, It is not an issue with ajax. It shows error without ajax too.

Comment: Is your problem with `callback(true);` always calling with same argument `true/false`?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi, I edited the question and issue is in bold letters

Comment: Problem with you are binding `$(document).on('click'` on every `function` call `confirmMsg`. Put those `click` event binding outside `confirmMsg` will fix your issue.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi, I didn't understand. If I put it outside, then how can I call it in callback? I added the fiddle with the question. If u know the answer, kindly help me by edit in the fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99449/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-arun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of these lines of code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#conf-yes', function()
{
    callback(true);
});
$(document).on('click', '#conf-no', function()
{
    callback(false);
});
```

You are adding the events each time its called, so they run multiple times. Try changing to this:

```
$('#conf-yes').off('click');
$('#conf-no').off('click');
$(document).on('click', '#conf-yes', function()
{
    callback(true);
});
$(document).on('click', '#conf-no', function()
{
    callback(false);
});
```

While it would probably be smarter to set up your JS so it only adds the event once (presumably outside of the time of call to that function), the .off() will remove the previous click events so when you add them again you won't have duplicates.

But if you want to move forward with that code, you could also shorten it a bit:

```
$('#conf-yes').off('click').on('click', function()
{
    callback(true);
});
$('#conf-no').off('click').on('click', function()
{
    callback(false);
});
```

Comment: Thank you lots.. the $('#conf-yes').off('click'); worked.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are binding `click` event multiple times on every click it binds new click.

You have to do

```
function conf_close() {
    $('.conf-cont-main').remove();
}
function confirmMsg(message, callback) {
    $('.conf-main').remove();
    var cont = '<div class="conf-cont-main"><div class="conf-main">\n\
    <span class="conf-close" onclick="conf_close()">X</span>\n\
    <div class="conf-head">\n\
    Confirm Action\n\
    </div>\n\
    <div class="conf-body">\n\
    ' + message + '\n\
    </div>\n\
    <div class="conf-button">\n\
    <button class="btn btn-blue-3 btn-sm btn-flat" id="conf-yes" onclick="conf_click(true);">Yes</button>\n\
    <button class="btn btn-blue-3 btn-sm btn-flat" id="conf-no" onclick="conf_click(false);">No</button>\n\
    </div>\n\
    </div></div>';
    $('body').prepend(cont);      
}

function conf_click(arg) {
    callback(arg);
}
```